# Long dates conversion to quarters (Capitalized with periods)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to convert the long dates to their respective quarters.

**Data**

```
id  date
a   10/1/2021
a   10/1/2021
a   7/1/2021
b   1/1/2021
b   2/1/2022
```

**Desired**

```
id  date
a   Q4.21
a   Q4.21
a   Q3.21
b   Q1.21
b   Q1.22
```

**Doing**

I believe python has this conversion script built in. However, I am not sure how to rearrange the format, capitalize and include a period.

```
df['date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.date, freq='Q')
```

Output of the following code is:

```
id  date
a   2021Q4
a   2021Q4
a   2021Q3
b   2022Q1
b   2022Q1
```

However, this is not the desired output I would like.
Any insight or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.quarter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Period.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.strftime.html) and specify the format string:

```
df['date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['date'], freq='Q').strftime('Q%q.%y')
```

`df`:

```
  id   date
0  a  Q4.21
1  a  Q4.21
2  a  Q3.21
3  b  Q1.21
4  b  Q1.22
```

Answer (score 1):

Try joining string columns while extracting the appropriate components.

```
df['qtr'] = 'Q' + df['date'].dt.quarter.astype(str) + '.' \
    + df['date'].dt.strftime('%y')

df
  id       date    qtr
0  a 2021-10-01  Q4.21
1  a 2021-10-01  Q4.21
2  a 2021-07-01  Q3.21
3  b 2021-01-01  Q1.21
4  b 2022-02-01  Q1.22
```

The reason why I chose this is because extracting the quarter number using `Q%q.%y`, as I first tried, didn't work on my computer. I localised the issue to `%q` on my computer (`%y` works fine).

Comment: Only `Period.strftime` has access to `%q`. `dt.strftime` only has access to the standard `strftime` parameters (which does not include `%q`. This method would require `df['date']` to be of type `datetime` while `PeriodIndex` would accept the column as is.

Comment: I wrote my answer against the original version of the question, which had nothing to do with a period index. It only had a date column in a MDY format.

Comment: I understand. I was just trying to say that `Q%q.%y` doesn't work on your machine because (I assume) you were trying `df['date'].dt.strftime('Q%q.%y')` which would not work. It is not an issue with `%q` on your computer specifically.